# How to get pagedlist size in android when using paging library with mvvm

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvvm, paging, pagedlist

please, I'm using android MVVM with retrofit and with paging library and the problem is I can't get size of `pagedlist`.
`pagedlist = 0` in UI always.

and the below code that the way how I get the list size.

```
 private void getAllAds() {
        userHomeViewModel.getHomeAllAdsPagedList().observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<AllAdsModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagedList<AllAdsModel> list) {
                allAdsModelPagedList = list;
                Toast.makeText(AllAdsActivity.this, ""+list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //list.size = 0!!!!
                initUserAllAds();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have something returned back in `list`, it's not the paging library issue; it's that you misconfigure the Paging List, or there is no data comes in from `Retrofit`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for your information the RecyclerView is displaying data well, but if I want to know the size of list, it = 0! and actually the data appear good, alot of other issues will disappear if I know the size of pagedlist..

Comment: Do you setup RecyclerView with PagedList in this `observer` ?

Comment: I don't use/know observer

Comment: adapter.submitList(allAdsModelPagedList); this inside initialize receylerview

Comment: You know the Observer at your code that you provided `Observer<PagedList<AllAdsModel>`

Comment: I use     private LiveData<PagedList<AllAdsModel>> pagedListLiveData; in UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PagedList` is loaded incrementally, so its `size` will change overtime and will always be 0 (with placeholders disabled) before calling `submitList`, and it has been given a chance to load some items.

You should instead look to take advantage of the APIs on `PagedListAdapter`.

If you're interested in the current size of the currently presented list, you can use `PagedListAdapter.currentList.size`

If you want to be notified when a new `PagedList` is presented, you can use `PagedListAdapter.onCurrentListChanged`. This method is called after initial load and diffutil runs, so it is stnchronous with when the new `PagedList` is presented.

Note that `PagedList.size` includes placeholders. In the case where you have placeholdersEnabled, but you're only interested in the loaded items you should use `PagedList.loadedCount`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean it is impossible to know PagedList size at first load ?

Comment: You can check the presented size after initial load, but to know the full size of a paginated list, you either need to finish loading all the pages or have some other way of fetching / knowing the size.